# conv. neural network, output and y-data dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am new to neural networks(using Keras, tf backend) and am trying to train a network to spot a specific pixel in a 200x200 image. The Input data features np arrays of the format (amount, 200,200,1) as they are black and white images with array values ranging from -0.5 to 0.5. The labelled y-data has the same format with every pixel of value 0 and 1 pixel of value 1.

When the data is imported, it looks like this:

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

My network looks like this:

```
train_images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis=3)
train_labels = np.expand_dims(train_labels, axis=3)
test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis=3)
test_labels = np.expand_dims(test_labels, axis=3)

print(train_images.shape) # (example, 200, 200, 1)
print(train_labels.shape) # (example,  200, 200, 1) 
print(test_images.shape)
print(test_labels.shape)

num_filters = 16
filter_size = 5
filter_size2 =3
pool_size = 2
input_shape=(200,200,1)
output_shape = input_shape

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
x= tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, filter_size, activation=tf.nn.relu)input_shape=input_shape, padding='same')(inputs)
x= tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, filter_size2, padding='same')(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x= tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_shape, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.summary()

model.compile('Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'],)

history = model.fit(train_images, to_categorical(train_labels), epochs=3,
          validation_data=(test_images, to_categorical(test_labels)))
```

When I flatten the layer to use a Dense layer I want softmax to calculate the probabilities for each pixel, but Dense seems to only take a 1D number and no array format tuple.
I was also thinking of changing the network to an output of 2 nodes (x and y coordinates) but when I upload the data with 2 coordinates it would again have format (amount, 1,1). So the output dimension wouldn't fit the y-data dimension.

I would be glad for any kind of help on how would be the best way to try and train the network to find the searched for pixel.

Comment: The `architecture` that you have used is for `Image Classification` i.e., the `Network` Predicts to which `Class` does the `Image` belong to. But as you want to predict about a part of an Image, yours is an **Object Detection** problem. Please refer this `Tensorflow Tutorial` (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection) or this Github Link (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Comments

> The architecture that you have used is for `Image Classification` i.e.,
> the Network Predicts to which Class does the Image belong to. But as
> you want to predict about a part of an Image, yours is an `Object Detection problem`. Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection) Tensorflow Tutorial
> or [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) Github Link for more details (paraphrased from Tensorflow Support)